# How to check if two numbers are sequential in JS? Codewars Kata

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve this kata:

You are given a list of unique integers arr, and two integers a and b. Your task is to find out whether or not a and b appear consecutively in arr, and return a boolean value (True if a and b are consecutive, False otherwise).

It is guaranteed that a and b are both present in arr.

Test examples:

```
consecutive([1, 3, 5, 7], 3, 7), false
consecutive([1, 3, 5, 7], 3, 1), true 
consecutive([1, 6, 9, -3, 4, -78, 0], -3, 4), true
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let index2 = arr.indexOf(b)
  let index1 = arr.indexOf(a)

    let diff = (index2) - (index1)

    if (diff > 1) {
        console.log(diff, 'false');
        return false
    } else {
        console.log(diff, 'true');
        return true
    }
}
```

The test examples are passing but then when I submit the solution, some other tests are not passing. I don't get to see the tests that are not passing so I'm stuck on this. Also, I thought that, in case a and b are the same number, so in case I had

```
cons([4, 6, 4, 5, 6], 4, 4)
```

my solution wouldn't pass this test, so how could I improve it?

Comment: Find the first number and see if the other number is in the index before or after it?

Comment: You are using indexOf multiple times inside the loop to look for the same values. That is horribly inneficient. Many of those tests are designed to timeout if you use inefficient approaches

Comment: @evolutionxbox fantastic reply XD it's the practical approach I'm having difficulties with!

Comment: @charlietfl your reply is SO efficient. Next time you try and help someone, tell them why what they're doing is wrong.

Comment: The point being the loop is not doing anything productive other than running the exact same code each time. So instead of running the code once... it runs as many times as length of the array(or match found). Time is not your friend in those exercises

Comment: @charlietfl actually the for loop makes no difference - just seems like redundant code to me since it has a definite return

Comment: @skara9 Certainly redundant but consider a huge array. Those tests are often designed to time out to make you focus on efficiency

Comment: @charlieftl i'm saying it returns the fn, so the loop only runs once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the reason your code isn't passing all the tests is because you are not taking into account that when `a` comes after `b`, diff will be negative.

So you should be doing

```js
let diff = Math.abs(index2 - index1)
```

---

Also the for loop doesn't seem to do anything so you can just delete it.

Comment: thanks a lot, your comment really helped! But 1) how did you know why my code wasn't passing all the tests? Just want to figure out if this is something I can read off of codewars or it's just a use case that I was missing 2) WHY would using indexOf multiple times be considered inefficient? I did just pass all the tests and many solutions used the same approach...

Comment: @geek101 1) you said it wasn't passing the tests - 2) its not that inefficient since you only run it twice, but you shouldn't run it in a loop over each element

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! won't forget about Math.abs() now XD

Answer (score 0):

**steps:**

1. Find index of given values
2. check if index of any one value + or - 1 is same as other.

**code:**

```js
function consecutive(number_list, value1,value2){
    var index_value_one = number_list.indexOf(value1);
  var index_value_two = number_list.indexOf(value2);
  
  if(index_value_one == (index_value_two + 1) || index_value_one == (index_value_two - 1)){
  return true;
  }
  return false;
  
}

console.log(consecutive([1, 3, 5, 7], 3, 7));
console.log(consecutive([1, 3, 5, 7], 3, 1));
console.log(consecutive([1, 6, 9, -3, 4, -78, 0], -3, 4));
```

**output:**
[image]